# Apache Spark error using hadoop to offload data to AWS S3

Tags: java, windows, amazon-web-services, apache-spark, hadoop

I'm using `Apache Spark` v2.3.1 and try to offload data to `AWS S3` after processing that. Something like that:

`data.write().parquet("s3a://" + bucketName + "/" + location);`

Configuration seems to be fine:

```
        String region = System.getenv("AWS_REGION");
        String accessKeyId = System.getenv("AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID");
        String secretAccessKey = System.getenv("AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY");

        spark.sparkContext().hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3a.impl", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem");
        spark.sparkContext().hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3a.awsRegion", region);
        spark.sparkContext().hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3a.awsAccessKeyId", accessKeyId);
        spark.sparkContext().hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3a.awsSecretAccessKey", secretAccessKey);
```

`%HADOOP_HOME%` leads to exactly the same version used by Spark (v2.6.5) and added into Path:

```
C:\>hadoop
Usage: hadoop [--config confdir] COMMAND
where COMMAND is one of:
  fs                   run a generic filesystem user client
  version              print the version
  jar <jar>            run a jar file
  checknative [-a|-h]  check native hadoop and compression libraries availability
  distcp <srcurl> <desturl> copy file or directories recursively
  archive -archiveName NAME -p <parent path> <src>* <dest> create a hadoop archive
  classpath            prints the class path needed to get the
                       Hadoop jar and the required libraries
  credential           interact with credential providers
  key                  manage keys via the KeyProvider
  daemonlog            get/set the log level for each daemon
 or
  CLASSNAME            run the class named CLASSNAME
```

So does `Maven`:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-aws</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.5</version>
    </dependency>
```

But I still get the following error on write. Any ideas why?

```
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.access0(Ljava/lang/String;I)Z
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.access0(Native Method) ~[hadoop-common-2.6.5.jar:?]
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.access(NativeIO.java:557) ~[hadoop-common-2.6.5.jar:?]
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.canRead(FileUtil.java:977) ~[hadoop-common-2.6.5.jar:?]
```

Answer (score 0):

yeah, I've missed one step. Put this: https://github.com/steveloughran/winutils/tree/master/hadoop-2.6.4/bin
to `%HADOOP_HOME%\bin`. Even if versions don't match (v2.6.5 vs v2.6.4), that still seems to be working.